# Running the Fit Logistic Curve to a Data Set script (MATLAB) by De Silva

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am unfamiliar with MATLAB and am trying to run [an existing script by De Silva](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31399-fit-logistic-curve-to-a-data-set) to fit a logistic curve to my data. It says to run the script 'Logistic.m' and a GUI will come up where you can enter a text file for the x values and a text file for the y values. I have the appropriate files for each file and have made sure all files are in the same directory.

I assume it is a user error on my part as their documentation indicates it should be very simple. However, I have not had success in getting the GUI to appear; only an interface where a plot and some data should be but are not. There is some path already entered but this is nothing I had put in.

[image]

I have tried running it with

```
Logistic('X_File.txt', 'Y_File.txt')
Logistic('test.txt')
Logistic()
```

I have already tried posting under the script directly but had not heard back. Apologies for the simplicity of the question. If it is not fitting for this forum, I can remove it.

Comment: Have you tried using the native [curve fitting tool](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/sftool.html) (if you have the relevant toolbox)? It would help to know your MATLAB version and a [mcve] (we don't have your txt files of data to reproduce this issue!).

Comment: I assume THAT is the GUI. Did you try changing the path in the text input?

Comment: @MatteoV Yes, I tried changing all the fields but when I hit 'find fit', an error occurs.

Comment: "an error occurs" doesn't say much, provide more info.

Comment: @Wolfie Running the other curve fitting tool did not seem to work... it did not like the file type, even when changed to the specified format. The MATLAB version is 9.10.0.1716447 (R2021a) Update 4. As for an example, the only information I provide to a program is two txt files with some values for x and for y (as I understand it). I did include the commands I used to call the script, which were all unsuccessful. I included the link in the original post because these are the steps/documentation which are very short.

Comment: @MatteoV `>> Logistic
Error using str2num (line 37)
Input must be a character vector or string scalar.

Error in Logistic>FindFit_Callback (line 335)
est_r = str2num(get(handles.est_r,'String'));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Logistic (line 30)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});`

Comment: You probably did not change the "min r" and/or "max r" fields.

Comment: It sounds like your issue is less about curve fitting and more about reading data from a file - can you use the curve fitting tool if you just load the data in first? There are two parts to this issue and it would be helpful to isolate the actual problem